# Instantiating Class in Ruby, Attributes not Showing Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class as follows:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name, :rating, :team_name
end
```

So I ran 'bundle exec rails console' and then

```
Player.create(:name => "Ben", :rating => 5, :team_name => "Brown")
```

However, this is what I get back:

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (7.0ms)  INSERT INTO "players" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 29 Mar 2014 04:24:31 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 29 Mar 2014 04:24:31 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Player id: 1, name: nil, rating: nil, team_name: nil, created_at: "2014-03-29 04:24:31", updated_at: "2014-03-29 04:24:31">
```

Why does the object that's created not have the properties I've assigned it?  This strikes me as really strange...

Any guidance on this one?

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: Do you have a migration that adds those attributes to the class?

Comment: `attr_accessor` is for creating instances and their accessor/mutator methods, it doesn't create database backed properties.

Comment: Add attr_accessible :name, :rating, :team_name
instead of attr_accessor

Answer (score -1):

```
Player.create(:name => "Ben", :rating => 5, :team_name => "Brown")
```

Here you are mass assigning attributes name, rating and team_name
So you need to tell `Player` model that above attributes can be mass assigned.
to allows mass assignment, you have to pass those attributes to attr_accessible method.

`attr_accessor` is used for creating getter and setter methods.
And getter and setter methods for database attributes are dynamically created, you don't need to create it.

so change

```
attr_accessor :name, :rating, :team_name
```

to

```
attr_accessible :name, :rating, :team_name
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?